# How to increase the post-processing resolution in three.js?

Tags: three.js, renderer, post-processing

I have a shader working on a scene (using the EffectComposer method), with a simple cube rotating in it.

When I only render my renderer, the cube has high resolution :

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```

When I render my composer without any setting, my shader is working but my cube get pixelated. So I tried this : https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/10238

Here it is ( I set the size of the composer depending of the pixel ratio screen value) :

```
let pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 0;
composer.setSize(window.innerWidth * pixelRatio, window.innerHeight * pixelRatio);
```

But after this my scene become very small as you can see bellow (black screen is my entire window).

Does anyone has any leads of what my problem is ? 
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Do you mind providing a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/)? BTW: It should be `let pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;`.

Comment: @Mugen87 yes sure. I tried on JsFiddle but it seems that my libs are called after my script but here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/7909/ or you can see it online here : http://www.michaelg.fr/lab_webgl/home3_compoer/

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/7965/. I'm not able to reproduce the issue on my laptop. However, the device has no retina display. I'm trying to test your fiddle on an iMac next week.

Comment: @Mugen87 thank you for the fiddle. Unfortunately it reproduces the issue on my retina Macbook. Any idea ? Thank you for your time